# Combining azure functions V2 dotnet from multiple assemblies

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm implementing Azure functions V2 in dotnet core. Let's say I have two assemblies (of type Azure function) containing Azure functions and I would like to deploy it in a way where azure functions from both assemblies would be loaded in Azure function host.

- Functions1.dll (contains functions A,B,C)
- Functions2.dll (contains functions D,E,F)

Expected Result:
Function app hosting functions (A,B,C,D,E,F)

I tried to plainly and simply reference these dlls, Function host started,initialized, but no functions were found.

Comment: Hi Biggles, may I know if the answer I provided helps your problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, we can deploy the function code in dll to Azure function, please refer to the steps below:

1. Build the project in visual studio and generate the "bin" and the functions in your project.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
2. Go to the path of your azure function by clicking "Advanced tools (Kudu)" button
   [image]
3. In Kudu, click "Debug console" --> "CMD" --> "site" --> "wwwroot", and drag the folders "bin", "Function2", "Function3" from local to the web page.
   [image]
4. Restart your azure function app, then you can run the two functions on portal.

If you want to deploy another function project to this function app, we can repeat the steps above. **But we need to focus on the differences and the repetition of the two function project in their "bin" folder. The differences and the repetition of the bin folder in these two function projects will cause a lot of problems, so I think deploy to Azure function from dll is not a good solution for us to do the deployment(especially there are two function projects).** You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment) to know some more solution to deploy azure function.